# Python Sockets - Data is being sent way too fast

Tags: python, python-sockets

I'm using python sockets to send data across however whenever I'm sending data to the client, it seems to miss my data unless **I'm debugging (which allows me to pause execution when needed).**

Server snippet:

```
def send_file(client_socket: socket):
    with open('client.py', 'rb') as file:
        while True:
            read_data = file.read()
            client_socket.sendall(read_data)
            if not read_data:
                client_socket.sendall('End'.encode())
                break
    print('Finished')
```

The server reports that it has finished and sent the 'end' message, but my client seems to be hanging on listening for too long, even though I thought adding a end message would help.
Client Snippet:

```
    with open('test.txt', 'wb') as file:
        while True:
            received_bytes = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
            if received_bytes == b'End':
                break
            file.write(received_bytes)
        # TODO: Restart client program
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
received_bytes = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
```

Does read `BUFFER_SIZE` or less bytes, depending on `BUFFER_SIZE` and message you send `End` might become part of `received_bytes` rather than whole `received_bytes` or be cut between subsequent `received_bytes`. Consider following example, let say your message is `HELLOWORLD` thus you do send `HELLOWORLDEnd` and `BUFFER_SIZE` equals `3` therefore `received_bytes` are subsequently

```
HEL
LOW
ORL
DEn
d
```

Thus last is clearly not `End`. You do not need special way of informing about end, see part of [`socket` Example from docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example):

```
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.sendall(data)
```

In your case this means not sending `End` and replacing

```
if received_bytes == b'End':
```

using

```
if not received_bytes:
```

EDIT after comment *server cannot send an empty message and so the client is still listening for data even though it has well sufficiently been sent*

If you must use end of message marker AT ANY PRICE, then consider using single byte for that purpose, which **never** appears in your message. For example if you elect `\x00` for this purpose, you might then do

```
    received_bytes = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    file.write(received_bytes.rstrip(b'\x00'))
    if received_bytes.endswith(b'\x00'):
        break
```

`.endswith` and `.rstrip` methods work for `bytes` same way like for `str`s. Thus this code does write `received_bytes` sans trailing `\x00` (note that `.rstrip` does not modify `received_bytes`) then if `received_bytes` `endswith` said byte `break`.

Comment: Buffer size is the same for both, and when I use if not received, the client hangs waiting for another buffer of data to come through. And the end message works when I'm debugging (aka. Full control of time in my program)

Comment: @JoySingh Right, because with the delays due to debugging, the final chunk of data from the file gets sent as a distinct packet, and the 'End' message gets sent in a packet of its own - which is the only case in which your current code can detect it.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you for the explanation. I'm wondering what alternatives exist since in my situation the server cannot send an empty message and so the client is still listening for data even though it has well sufficiently been sent

Comment: @JoySingh I edited my answer to include possible end of message implementation